# How to write a simple malloc function in c

Tags: c, linux, malloc

As an assignment in operating systems we have to write our own code for malloc and free in C programming language, I know if i asked the code for it there is no point of me to study. i'm facing the problem of not knowing where to include initializing  char array with 50000 bytes and making two lists free and used. in my function i can't trigger malloc or free to happen automatically. and a 3rd party main program will be used to test my functions.....
if my file is mymalloc.c or what ever

```
    void* myalloc(size_t size)
    {
        //code for allocating memory
    }
    void myfree(void *ptr)
    {
        //code for free the memory
    }
```

where do the code for initiating memory space and lists will go..

Comment: This is remarkably similar to [Writing a simulation of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171639/writing-a-simulation-of-malloc).  It isn't identical, but my answer there can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have to implement a memory manager. So you don't have to use `brk`, `sbrk`, ...
Just put used memory in a simple array and fragment it somehow. Since it's homework you want to make it as simple as possible or else you run into problems due to complexity/time constraints of your assignment.

You only have to decide which tactic you want to use. I'd suggest to use the [buddy system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation). Though it's a bit more complicated than the most simple ones.. maybe fixed sized fragmentation is simpler..

Maybe [this](http://www.helenos.org/doc/design/html.chunked/mm.html#id2532928) is also a good read.

Don't do something low-level as suggested in the other answers..

Comment: I agree, even if I've suggested the hard way :)

Comment: thanks bro. finally i find a way to code it.. my code is work fine. no segmentation or any fault appears. but when my required size exceeds 3306 bytes it gives me a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

I will provide you with the basic concept which you can use to write your own code for malloc() and free() functions using C.

1. Assume that we have a contiguous block of memory of a certain size. It will be our abstract sense of memory which will carry all the requested memory allocations plus the data structures that are used to hold data about those allocated blocks.
2. We use a simple linked list to carry the data related to the allocated as well as free blocks of memory.

Its structure is as follows.

```
struct block{
         size_t size;  /*Specifies the size of the block to which it refers*/
         int free;  /*This is the flag used to identify whether a block is free 
                     or not*/                           
         struct block *next;   /*This points to the next metadata block*/
   };
```

3. You will need 2 source files for this purpose. One is mymalloc.h which is the header file which contains the initialization parts and the function prototypes of the rest of the functions that we are going to implement. The other is the mymalloc.c source file which contains all the necessary function implementations.
4. There needs to be a function to initialize the first free memory block.
   And another function to split a block of memory which has more than enough space to give to the requested size. And another method to scan through the linked list and merge any consecutive blocks that are free, so that it prevents external fragmentation.

Note: We use the First-fit-algorithm to find a free block to allocate memory.

I think this will help anyone who is in search of a simple way to write their own malloc and free functions using C. Please follow the following link for a detailed explanation.

http://tharikasblogs.blogspot.com/p/how-to-write-your-own-malloc-and-free.html

Answer (score 1):

The implementation greatly depends upon operating system and architecture, anyhow you may take a look at this: http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/lib_2ansi_2malloc_8c-source.html

(and study how it works!).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a unix system you can look the manual of `brk` and `sbrk`. Those system calls "push/set" the limit of the heap.

Using those you can manage your memory pages, allocating them as you need.

I would advise a chained-list to manage your different allocated spaces and building functions to split them or to merge them if they are free.

If you need to try your code with high-level applications, you can name your functions malloc/free, compile them to a shared-object (.so) and then use `LD_PRELOAD` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables to load your .so and replace system's malloc.
Every command you call then will use your shared object and thus your malloc, telling you if your malloc is stable or if it fails to comply with reality.

If you need a clear example of this i'd be happy to put some code here, but I do not want to make my answer too hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could make a fake malloc which always fail

```
 /* fake malloc */
 void* myalloc(size_t sz)
 { return NULL; }
```

but that is "cheating". You want to make a `malloc` which is useful.

You probably want to make a system call which asks the kernel for memory. Of course, you'll need the symetrical syscall to release memory. On Linux and many Posix systems you'll often use [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) and [munmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap) syscalls.

(You could also use [sbrk](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk), but using `mmap` with `munmap` is easier and more general)

The idea is that you get big chunks of memory (with `mmap`) and then you manage smaller memory zones inside. The interesting detail is how to manage these smaller zones. You may want to deal with large `malloc` differently than "small" allocations.

You really want to read [wikipedia page on memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a global static variable that is initialized to zero. Then check that variable at the start of your `malloc` and `free` function. In your `malloc` function, if the variable is zero then initialize whatever you need, and then set the variable to non-zero. In your `free` function, just return if the variable is zero.

Answer (score 0):

More like that, is a simple malloc :

```
void* my_malloc(size_t size)
{
 return (sbrk(size));
}
```

man sbrk will help you.

The problem now is to create a free and to create a efficient malloc :-)

if you want to test your malloc you can do like this :

$> LD_PRELOAD=/mypath/my_malloc.so /bin/ls

but you need to create a dynamic library before because malloc is a .so