# how to implement a buddy allocator when we don't know the size of available memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

How can you implement [a buddy allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation) when the total size of memory is unknown? Ie, if I'm implementing a malloc function using `brk`/`sbrk`, I can't know the total size of the memory available to my process, can I? Because of virtual memory, the total size of my memory space isn't even really known, is it?

How can you use a buddy allocator for something like this? Do you just assume a reasonable size to construct a buddy-allocator tree for, and somehow grow it if you need to?

Comment: If you are doing this on embedded hardware, then you know exactly how much memory you have and you can statically allocate a memory structure in RAM.  There are OS dependent functions that will give you available memory, but that is not a way to write your code -- you just don't grab all of available memory for your one process.  Also, you can't grow it after you first allocate the entire memory block, since pointers are not movable (at least in C).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to first initialize your buddy allocator with a smaller amount of memory. And when the memory is not enough for the next allocation, double the size of previously allocated memory and you get a new larger buddy allocator.

---

I am wondering why you must use buddy system for memory allocator? Most modern allocators maintain slab structures for small allocations and deal large allocations with `mmap` calls. This scheme is faster and more memory efficient than buddy system.

Comment: "I am wondering why you must use buddy system for memory allocator..." I don't have to, but I've heard it suggested (eg, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9176812/598940), and I was unsure how it could be applied to this situation.

Comment: Also see mention of jemalloc here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation#Implementation_and_efficiency